# How to align the column widths of two tables

Tags: html, thymeleaf

I've currently got two tables, one for past and one for upcoming events, as seen [in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvV2A.png)

As you can see, the widths of the columns in the first table isn't aligned with those in the second (since the event name of the second is longer than the first). I was wondering if it was possible to align them while still dynamically adjusting column width, or if the only solution is to set the column width beforehand.

Comment: what you have tried so far?  ....please add some codes

Answer (score 0):

you can control the width of column by setting css `max-width`  ,hope this will help you to control the overflow even if your  content have dynamic length.I added an example with max-width below.

```css
p{
  max-width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam semper diam at erat pulvinar, at pulvinar felis blandit. Vestibulum volutpat tellus diam, consequat gravida libero rhoncus ut. Maecenas imperdiet felis nisi, fringilla luctus felis hendrerit sit amet. Pellentesque interdum, nisl nec interdum maximus, augue diam porttitor lorem, et sollicitudin felis neque sit amet erat.</p>
```